# How do I print the lowest root?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I'm trying to write a program that the user inputs a number and the program gives you the root and power of that number. However, I only want it to print the lowest root (for example: for `64` it'd print `4**3` not `8**2`). I was wondering if anyone could help me rearrange the loops to do that.

```
n = int(input('enter a number = '))
found = False
power = 2
while power < 6 :
    root = 0
    while root ** power < n :
        root = root + 1
    if root ** power == n :
        print(n, 'is equal to', root, '**', power)
        found = True
    power = power + 1
if not found:
    print(n, 'does not have a root to some power in this range')
```

Comment: So, what prevents you from stopping the loop after you find the first answer?

Comment: Currently the outer loop iterates on `power` and the inner loop iterates on `root`. Try to swap them so the outer loop iterates on `root` and the inner loop iterates on `power`.

Comment: How do you define "lowest root"? In your example, why isn't 2\*\*6 the "lowest root"?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk The power doesn't include 6, so the program wouldn't print 2**6

Comment: @DYZ The first answer would be 8**2 because my program finds the lowest power first, but I'm trying to only find the second answer which has the lowest root but not necessarily the lowest power